# How to remove everything after the first occurrence of a number in a string?

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove everything after the first number (including the number).

Examples:

```
banner400x300   
icon80x42        
bla bla55x44
```

should be:

```
banner   
icon  
bla bla
```

I tried something like this:

```
preg_replace("/([^0-9]*[0-9]*)(.*)/", "$1", $str);
```

But it's including the first numbers :(

What is a good way of doing that? Thanks :)

Comment: The good way consists to match all that isn't a number from the start of the string with `preg_match`, not to replace. In this way you don't need to parse the string until the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that the first capturing group contains `[0-9]*` and are thus re-inserted into the result with the `$1` backreference.

The simplest regex for this will be

```
preg_replace('~\d.*~', '', $s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xWJj1l/1)

The `\d.*` regex finds the first digit with `\d` (because the string is processed from left to right) and `.*` will match up to the end of the line (to match across linebreaks, add `s` modifier: `'~\d.*~s'`).

[PHP demo](http://ideone.com/hPaLLV):

```
$str = "banner400x300\nicon80x42\nbla bla55x44";
$result = preg_replace('~\d.*~', '', $str);
echo $result;
```